# Samba4 member server smbclient fails with NT_STATUS_NO_LOGON_SERVERS

Tags: domain, samba4

I am attempted to resolve a problem with a new CentOS 7 (samba 4) member server in my domain.  It could join the domain (using realm command) but it is not responding to smb queries properly.  I used the smbclient program and compared the output against working servers and the problem server, and discovered unusual output.

I have selinux disabled, iptables disabled.  I confirmed this host (lserver) is part of the domain using 'realm', it can ping the DC, name resolution is working.

When I run with -U "MYDOMAIN\administrator" it fails:

```
smbclient  -U "MYDOMAIN\administrator" -L lserver -d 10
INFO: Current debug levels:
  all: 10
  tdb: 10
  printdrivers: 10
  lanman: 10
  smb: 10
  rpc_parse: 10
  rpc_srv: 10
  rpc_cli: 10
  passdb: 10
  sam: 10
  auth: 10
  winbind: 10
  vfs: 10
  idmap: 10
  quota: 10
  acls: 10
  locking: 10
  msdfs: 10
  dmapi: 10
  registry: 10
  scavenger: 10
  dns: 10
  ldb: 10
  tevent: 10
lp_load_ex: refreshing parameters
Initialising global parameters
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
INFO: Current debug levels:
  all: 10
  tdb: 10
  printdrivers: 10
  lanman: 10
  smb: 10
  rpc_parse: 10
  rpc_srv: 10
  rpc_cli: 10
  passdb: 10
  sam: 10
  auth: 10
  winbind: 10
  vfs: 10
  idmap: 10
  quota: 10
  acls: 10
  locking: 10
  msdfs: 10
  dmapi: 10
  registry: 10
  scavenger: 10
  dns: 10
  ldb: 10
  tevent: 10
Processing section "[global]"
doing parameter security = ads
doing parameter workgroup = MYDOMAIN
doing parameter server string = Linux Server
doing parameter netbios name = lserver
doing parameter log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
doing parameter max log size = 50
doing parameter log level = 10
doing parameter unix extensions = no
doing parameter load printers = No
doing parameter printcap name = /dev/null
doing parameter dns proxy = No
doing parameter wins server = 172.31.254.31
doing parameter printing = bsd
doing parameter print command = lpr -r -P'%p' %s
doing parameter lpq command = lpq -P'%p'
doing parameter lprm command = lprm -P'%p' %j
doing parameter guest ok = yes
doing parameter interfaces = 172.31.254.38 127.0.0.1
pm_process() returned Yes
lp_servicenumber: couldn't find homes
added interface ens192 ip=172.31.254.38 bcast=172.31.254.255 netmask=255.255.255.0
added interface lo ip=127.0.0.1 bcast=127.255.255.255 netmask=255.0.0.0
Netbios name list:-
my_netbios_names[0]="LSERVER"
Client started (version 4.4.4).
Enter MYDOMAIN\administrator's password: 
Opening cache file at /var/lib/samba/gencache.tdb
Opening cache file at /var/lib/samba/lock/gencache_notrans.tdb
sitename_fetch: No stored sitename for 
internal_resolve_name: looking up lserver#20 (sitename (null))
name lserver#20 found.
remove_duplicate_addrs2: looking for duplicate address/port pairs
Connecting to 172.31.254.38 at port 445
Socket options:
        SO_KEEPALIVE = 0
        SO_REUSEADDR = 0
        SO_BROADCAST = 0
        TCP_NODELAY = 1
        TCP_KEEPCNT = 9
        TCP_KEEPIDLE = 7200
        TCP_KEEPINTVL = 75
        IPTOS_LOWDELAY = 0
        IPTOS_THROUGHPUT = 0
        SO_REUSEPORT = 0
        SO_SNDBUF = 2626560
        SO_RCVBUF = 1061296
        SO_SNDLOWAT = 1
        SO_RCVLOWAT = 1
        SO_SNDTIMEO = 0
        SO_RCVTIMEO = 0
        TCP_QUICKACK = 1
        TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT = 0
 session request ok
Doing spnego session setup (blob length=96)
got OID=1.2.840.48018.1.2.2
got OID=1.2.840.113554.1.2.2
got OID=1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.10
got principal=not_defined_in_RFC4178@please_ignore
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_spnego' registered
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5' registered
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5_sasl' registered
GENSEC backend 'spnego' registered
GENSEC backend 'schannel' registered
GENSEC backend 'naclrpc_as_system' registered
GENSEC backend 'sasl-EXTERNAL' registered
GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp' registered
GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp_resume_ccache' registered
GENSEC backend 'http_basic' registered
GENSEC backend 'http_ntlm' registered
Starting GENSEC mechanism spnego
Starting GENSEC submechanism ntlmssp
     negotiate: struct NEGOTIATE_MESSAGE
        Signature                : 'NTLMSSP'
        MessageType              : NtLmNegotiate (1)
        NegotiateFlags           : 0x62088215 (1644724757)
               1: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
               0: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_OEM    
               1: NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET   
               1: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN   
               0: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SEAL   
               0: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_DATAGRAM
               0: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_LM_KEY 
               0: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NETWARE
               1: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM   
               0: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NT_ONLY
               0: NTLMSSP_ANONYMOUS        
               0: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_OEM_DOMAIN_SUPPLIED
               0: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_OEM_WORKSTATION_SUPPLIED
               0: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_THIS_IS_LOCAL_CALL
               1: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
               0: NTLMSSP_TARGET_TYPE_DOMAIN
               0: NTLMSSP_TARGET_TYPE_SERVER
               0: NTLMSSP_TARGET_TYPE_SHARE
               1: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_EXTENDED_SESSIONSECURITY
               0: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_IDENTIFY
               0: NTLMSSP_REQUEST_NON_NT_SESSION_KEY
               0: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_TARGET_INFO
               1: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_VERSION
               1: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128    
               1: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH
               0: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_56     
        DomainNameLen            : 0x0000 (0)
        DomainNameMaxLen         : 0x0000 (0)
        DomainName               : *
            DomainName               : ''
        WorkstationLen           : 0x0000 (0)
        WorkstationMaxLen        : 0x0000 (0)
        Workstation              : *
            Workstation              : ''
        Version: struct ntlmssp_VERSION
            ProductMajorVersion      : NTLMSSP_WINDOWS_MAJOR_VERSION_6 (6)
            ProductMinorVersion      : NTLMSSP_WINDOWS_MINOR_VERSION_1 (1)
            ProductBuild             : 0x0000 (0)
            Reserved: ARRAY(3)
                [0]                      : 0x00 (0)
                [1]                      : 0x00 (0)
                [2]                      : 0x00 (0)
            NTLMRevisionCurrent      : NTLMSSP_REVISION_W2K3 (15)
Got challenge flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x62898215
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
  NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_TARGET_TYPE_DOMAIN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_EXTENDED_SESSIONSECURITY
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_TARGET_INFO
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_VERSION
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH
NTLMSSP: Set final flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x62088215
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
  NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_EXTENDED_SESSIONSECURITY
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_VERSION
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH
NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x62088215
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
  NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_EXTENDED_SESSIONSECURITY
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_VERSION
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH
SPNEGO login failed: No logon servers
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_NO_LOGON_SERVERS
```